# Promise error: llegal arguments: function string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why when try call this method the promise cause the error: `llegal arguments: function string`,

```
const changePassword = function(context, user, newPass){


   return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { 
    try {
      hash = bcrypt.hashSync(newPass, 10);
      const result =  await context.db("users").where('id', user.id).update({
        password: hash,
        old_passwod: user.password
      });  

      resolve("Senha alterada");

    } catch (err){
      reject(new Error('Não foi possivel alterar a senha! '+err));
    }
  });
```

What's happing?

Comment: you don't need to use both of them, either use async/await or promise. its now returning promise of promise..

Comment: How are you calling it? also what `db` do you use to update the model?

Comment: use await before bcrypt.hash....